# High fantasy books series with telepathic avian race and armadillos

Tags: story-identification, books

This series has at least 3 books. I read the first 2 or 3 in 2013/14 and I think the 3rd or 4th had just recently come out at the time.

All I remember are small details. The main character met an avian race that communicated telepathically through images. At some point, the main character also found a race of underground(?) armadillos with crystal/very hard shells. The main character came to the realization that the land/continent had been inhabited by a succession of different races with humans just being the latest in line.

I also remember the main characterhaving a daughter who I think took over as the main character in the second or third book. Her description said something about her mouth curving naturally into a smile.

Slaying a dragon was maybe a plot point in the first book?

Comment: Sorry, it's late so can't write it up properly.  Pretty sure that's Knaak's [Dragonrealm](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53041-dragonrealm) series.

Comment: @eshier Yes, through probably the compilation series [Legends of the Dragonrealm](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53043-legends-of-the-dragonrealm). The avian race are the *Seekers* and the armadillos are the *Quel*. The girl is Sharissa, daughter of Dru Zeree: *Her smile - a true smile, not the one formed by the natural curve of her mouth - caused a twinge within him that he pretended to ignore*. We meet her in [volume II](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8691852-legends-of-the-dragonrealm-vol-ii).

Comment: The statement about the different races is made by the Lady Gwendolyn: *“These lands have seen many races rule. Each has had its cycle and it appears the time for humans is close at hand.*

Comment: @JohnRennie Yes, it's Legends of the Dragonrealm! Thanks so much.

Comment: @eshier Are you going to write an answer? If not I'll add a community wiki answer.

Comment: Sorry, forgot all about it.  Go ahead & answer.  No need for community wiki as far as I'm concerned. You have a ton more details than I remembered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [eshier pointed out in a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255139/high-fantasy-books-series-with-telepathic-avian-race-and-armadillos#comment701964_255139) these are the [Dragonrealm](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53041-dragonrealm) books by Richard A. Knaak from the early 1990s, but these were republished as [Legends of the Dragonrealm](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53043-legends-of-the-dragonrealm) around 2010 and it's this later version that you are describing.

The avian race are the *Seekers* and the armadillos are the *Quel*. The girl is *Sharissa*, daughter of *Dru Zeree*. The quote you remember is from the second volume:

> Her smile - a true smile, not the one formed by the natural curve of her mouth - caused a twinge within him that he pretended to ignore.

The statement about the different races is made by the *Lady Gwendolyn*:

> "These lands have seen many races rule. Each has had its cycle and it appears the time for humans is close at hand."